# What is the test-retest correlation for HEXACO personality?

Tags: measurement, personality, correlation

I am wanting to get estimates of the test-retest correlation for the six HEXACO domains. I'm curious to obtain estimates of test-retest correlation over various time frames (e.g., 1 month, 1 years, 2 years, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet found HEXACO domain estimates. I've had a lock through the main articles listed as references on http://hexaco.org/references but they seem to focus more on internal structure.

However, the HEXACO-PI is quite similar to the the NEO-PI in terms of number of items per domain and the general approach to trait measurement. Thus, I would expect that NEO-PI stability would provide a ballpark of what to expect. The following is a summary of few studies from the Wikipedia article on the NEO-PI.

> - The test retest reliability of an early version of the NEO after 3 months was: N = .87, E = .91, O = .86.[14]
> - The test retest reliability reported in the manual of the NEO PI-R over 6 years was: N = .83, E = .82, O = .83, A = .63, C = .79.
> - A 2001 study by Kurtz and Parrish[15] on the short-term test-retest reliability yielded coefficients of α = .91–.93 for domains and α
>     =.70–.91 for facets after a one-week interval. ...
> - A 2006 study by Terracciano et al.[16] on the long-term test-retest reliability yielded coefficients of α = .78–.85 for domains and α =
>     .57–.82 for facets after a 10-year interval.

[SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_NEO_Personality_Inventory)

#### References

- McCrae, R. R.; Costa, P. T. (1983). "Joint factors in self-reports and ratings: Neuroticism, extraversion and openness to experience". Personality and Individual Differences 4 (3): 245–255. doi:10.1016/0191-8869(83)90146-0.
- Kurtz J. E., Parrish C. L. (2001). "Semantic response consistency and protocol validity in structured personality assessment: The case of the NEO PI-R". Journal of Personality Assessment 76 (2): 315–332. doi:10.1207/S15327752JPA7602_12. PMID 11393463.
- Terracciano, A.; Abdel-Khalek,et al (2005). "National Character Does Not Reflect Mean Personality Trait Levels in 49 Cultures". Science 310 (5745): 96–100. doi:10.1126/science.1117199. PMC 2775052. PMID 16210536.